# Can I upload italic and/or bold text to my firebase database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want users to be able to make part of their posts to have italics and/or bold text, my question is, would it remain italic/bold once it's uploaded to the database? and once I download it would it remain that way again?

Comment: HTML can be your friend as HTML is basically a text and can be stored easily in Firebase and all you need to do is to make the attributed String from HTML on which you can find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase doesn't store text with decorations, just plain old strings.  If you want to store decorations, you'll have to find a way to encode that information into the string that you store.

Answer (score 0):

You can not decorate the letters in the database, you can change the shape of the font by means of the editors and display them on the user page